# Build a document library file structure as a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, rest

I was wondering if there is a way that I can (more simply that writing my own logic) to create a JS object that has a document libary file structure. E.G.

```
object = {
    foldername {
       file {
         url
       }
    },
      file {
         url
       }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone will correct me if I am wrong

I think (for performance reasons) the REST API Microsoft built, dives into the SQL server (database layer)

So distinction if an Item is a File Or Folder is made by SharePoint (the Application layer).

That means the REST data you get back is flat, and the metadata will indicate if something is a file or folder.